# Can anybody identify this piece of pottery?

Tags: identification

[image]

[image]

I bought this at a local "picker shop" and need to know if anyone can identify it. I have another picture, but it will only let me upload one per question, and I'd like to make sure this is the place to ask this question before asking a second.

I've not been able to translate the text either, and a close friend of mine thinks it could be a production or line number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The writing is in Tajik. It says: "Abu Ali Sina 1000 years". It commemorates the 1000th birthday of the philosopher known in the West as [Avicenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avicenna). The bowl was presumably made in Tajikistan.

Comment: So do you know what its worth?